# SeekBar с отрицательным значением Android Studio

Tags: android

Могу ли я каким-то образом получить ползунок с диапазоном значений, допустим, от -100 до 100? На самом деле, могу, находил пару постов на форумах, но довольно стареньких. Может что-то актуальнее уже есть. И, собственно, самый главный вопрос после этого. Могу ли я сделать, чтобы шкала прогресса заполнялась в обе стороны?

Если что, рисовал в пейнте, не судите))
[image]

Comment: Например с помощью [этой библиотеки](https://github.com/vashisthg/StartPointSeekBar). Если поискать, думаю найдутся и другие.

Comment: @eugeneek Спасибо, это подойдет

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на забугорном stackoverflow, понравился второй ответ, сделал так же, работает отлично. да и с кастомизацией можно побаловаться.
[клик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415096/seekbar-for-two-values-50-0-50)